# Fullcalendar - How to select an area and create an event from a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I saw a bunch of similar questions, but their old and not really answered.
I am trying to create an event by selecting an area on a touch (mobile) device.

I am using [JQuery Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and in the options I do the following:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
     cell.addTouch();
},
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
     element.draggable();
}
```

This allows me to interact with an existing event: I can drag it, resize it. But I cannot create an event by selecting an area.

Did someone actually managed to do that?